# *Единогласно* - в каких случаях можно использовать данное слово?

Tags: семантика, стилистическая-сочетаемость

Единогласно. В каких случаях данное слово уместно использовать? Простите у меня скудное знание русского языка вообще.

Answer (score 4):

Есть два малозатратных способа очень быстро получить информацию: сайт Грамота.Ру и Национальный корпус русского языка.

**1.Толковый словарь на Грамота.РУ:**

ЕДИНОГЛАСНЫЙ, -ая, -ое; -сен, -сна, -сно. =Единодушный. Е-ое мнение. Е-ые заверения, уверения в чём-л. // Принятый всеми, участвующими в голосовании. Е-ое решение. Е-ое избрание на пост премьер-министра. <Единогласно, нареч. Решение принято е. Проголосовали е.

**2. Нацкорпус:**

Это предложение принято общим собранием единогласно.

Зато комиссия единогласно одобрила установку памятника известному учёному Владимиру Далю.

Авторы альманаха почти единогласно сходятся во мнении.

И Вы можете сделать **вывод**, что **прямым** значением слова является единогласное принятие решения при голосовании. В то же время слово развивает и **переносное значение**: единогласно (единодушно) сходиться во мнении.

Answer (score 0):

В наше время можно найти всё в толковых словарях прямо в сети. И для этого слова [нашлась](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/798074) страничка.

Обычно это слово употребляют в тех случаях, когда все решили что-то одинаково.